# Como sair de uma SPA (Single Page Application) do AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, html5, angular-routes

Tenho seguinte código:

```
var app = angular.module("appSystem", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/teste", {templateUrl: './view/teste.html', controller: 'testeController'})
    .when("/about", {templateUrl: './view/sobre.html', controller: 'sobreController'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: "/app"});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

#### Imaginemos a seguinte situação

O site tem páginas estáticas e tem links em sua barra de navegação para elas, suponhamos que temos *Home*, *Login* e *Cadastro*, além dessas páginas estáticas temos uma, chamada *Aplicação*, onde é uma SPA que eu uso o **Angular**.

- Essas duas páginas que estão na configuração do *app* são as minhas *views* hipotéticas.
- A url base para a SPA definida no html é `<base href="/aplicacao" />`

O restante está tudo rodando e não vem ao caso aqui.

#### Como eu consigo sair do SPA?

Ou seja, dado que eu tinha minha barra de navegação que fazia requisições ao servidor pra mudança de páginas, com essa configuração de rotas tudo muda.
Como eu faço para que definir dentro do Angular que as rotas estabelecidas para os links na barra de navegação (e também em algum rodapé) sejam atendidas fora do SPA?

Comment: Uma saída seria implementar iframes. Outra, Utilize <a href='[link]' target="_blank">`.

Comment: Você esta usando o modo de rotas html5, `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na SPA, você pode por um botão pra sair ou em alguma função retornar a alguma url da home, você pode usar o `window.location.assign("http://exemplo.com.br/home");` do javascript.

Comment: Cara, essa forma funciona também mas acabei utilizando a forma comentada pelo @OnoSendai!